# Optimise/merge almost identical lines with start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following rows:

| id | status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-04-14 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-04-15 | 2023-04-18 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-04-30 | 9999-12-31 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-02 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-03 | 2023-04-05 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-15 | 2023-04-20 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-25 | 9999-12-31 |

I would like to transform the data in the following way:

| id | status | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-04-18 |
| 111 | 1 | 2023-04-30 | 9999-12-31 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-05 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-15 | 2023-04-20 |
| 222 | 1 | 2023-04-25 | 9999-12-31 |

How can I write an SQL query for this?

P.s.

```
SELECT '111' AS id, '1' AS status,  '2023-04-14'::date AS start_date, '2023-04-14'::date AS end_date UNION 
SELECT '111', '1', '2023-04-15', '2023-04-18' UNION 
SELECT '111', '1', '2023-04-30', '9999-12-31' UNION 
SELECT '222', '1', '2023-04-01', '2023-04-02' UNION 
SELECT '222', '1', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-05' UNION 
SELECT '222', '1', '2023-04-15', '2023-04-20' UNION 
SELECT '222', '1', '2023-04-25', '9999-12-31';
```

Comment: This is a classic "islands and gaps" problem. You're looking for islands. You'll find plenty of articles online explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to determine where the "islands" start, where there is no overlap. Then use a cumulative sum based on date arithmetic:

```
select id, status, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from (
      select d.*,
      sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date - integer '1' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id, status order by start_date) as grp
      from (
            select d.*,
            lag(end_date) over (partition by id, status order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from mytable d
      ) d
    ) d
group by id, status, grp
order by id, status, min(start_date);
```

Using `CTE` can be :

```
with cte as (
  select d.*,
  lag(end_date) over (partition by id, status order by start_date) as prev_end_date
  from mytable d
),
cte2 as (
  select *,
  sum(case when prev_end_date >= start_date - integer '1' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id, status order by start_date) as grp
  from cte
)
select id, status,  min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from cte2
group by id, status, grp
order by id, status, min(start_date);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Iurgh9CR)